# Angular material drag and drop for multi level nested data

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, draggable, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have few columns and each column have few small sections which have some fields in it.
[image]

I need to apply angular material drag and drop to this, so then,
I should be able to move the Groups within the column
also should be able to move the groups across the column
Move fields within the groups (order of the fields will be changed)
Move field across the groups( so field from group 2 can go inside the group 1 or group 4)

I'm struggling to achieve this.

Here is the link for the sample I have created

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-connected-lists-gtckyc?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that's existed from 2019 and while there doesn't seem to be an appetite to fix it, there are work arounds in the github issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16671